# How to get file contents of a file in php using a variable in the file name

Tags: php, variables, file-get-contents

I am using a Date picker solution that allows a user to search for data elements for previous days. Once of the things I would like to do is open text files on the page using the date entered as part of the file name. How do you include a variable as part of a filename to open?

```
<?php
$date=date('Y-m-d');
$date_arr=explode('-',$date);
$date1 = $_GET['datepicker'];
$date2=Date("M-d",mktime(0,0,0,$date_arr[1],$date_arr[2]-1,$date_arr[0]));
?>
```

Here I am trying to display the contents of a file with $date1 in the file name:

```
<?php
$my_file = file_get_contents("$date1_name_of_file.txt");
echo $my_file;
?>
```

so if the user typed in Aug-01 the name of the file I would want to load would be:
Aug-01_blah_blah_blah.txt

Comment: Try `$my_file = file_get_contents($date1_name_of_file . ".txt");`

Comment: `$my_file = file_get_contents("{$date1}_name_of_file.txt");`

Comment: Thanks Mark, Your suggestion worked perfectly for what I needed. Appreciate the help.